# how to grab the image from FacebookLogin

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

How do I print out the image from

```
print((result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "picture.data.url") as? Any)
```

I know that the following prints out the data and url but I just need the URL section.

```
print((result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "picture") as? Any)
```

any advise?

I am using FacebookLogin SDK

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: You can create the image URL on your own if you have the userId,

```
let facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
```

Here is how you can get id,name,email and profile picture url from facebook login. I use this code in my app and it works.

```
func fetchFacebookFields() {
        LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email","public_profile"], from: nil) {
            (result, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let result = result else { return }
            if result.isCancelled { return }
            else {
                GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "first_name, last_name, email"]).start() {
                    (connection, result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    if
                        let fields = result as? [String:Any],
                        let userID = fields["id"] as? String,
                        let firstName = fields["first_name"] as? String,
                        let lastName = fields["last_name"] as? String,
                        let email = fields["email"] as? String

                    {
                        let facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
                        print("firstName -> \(firstName)")
                        print("lastName -> \(lastName)")
                        print("email -> \(email)")
                        print("facebookProfileUrl -> \(facebookProfileUrl)")
                        APPDELEGATEOBJ.makeRootVC(vcName : "MainTabBarVC")

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```